# How to declare/define a file-static internal function that can access private members?

Tags: c++

Suppose this situation :

A.h

```
class A{
  private:
  int a;
  //...
  int a_function();
};
```

A.cpp

```
static void helper(A * this_){
  // need to do stuff with this_->a
}

int A::a_function(){
  helper(this);
}
```

The idea is to have this helper function, which only purpose is to breakdown `a_function` to make the code more readable. It should not be exported in the .o (as usual static functions).

But how to make it have access to the private members (in a readable way, with no pointer hacks) ?

(the ideal would even to make it a member function, but I think it's even less possible...)

Comment: Why not simply make `helper()` a `private` member function of class `A` (optionally it can be `static`, but that seems pointless if you are passing it a pointer to `A` for it to work on)?    If you insist on it being outside class `A`, declare it as a `friend`.

Answer (score 0):

You can declare `helper()` a `friend`:

```
//A.h
class A {
private:
    int a;
    //...
    int a_function();

    friend void helper(A* this_);
};
```

```
//A.cpp
static void helper(A* this_) {
    this_->a;
}

int A::a_function() {
    helper(this);
}
```

For more info, see https://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/inheritance/ or https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/friend.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using non-member, non-friend functions. They enforce accessing data types through their interfaces and make using the class easier and using it incorrectly harder.

```cpp
//A.hpp
class A{
    //If these are only return/assignment expressions,
    //consider making the member variable public.
    int GetA() const noexcept;
    void SetA(int newA) noexcept;
private:
    int a;
    //...
};


//A.cpp

static int helper(A& a){
    //Example usage...
    //a.GetA();
    //...
    //int newA{};
    //a.SetA(newA);
    //return newA;
}
```